# Trouble with overlapping instances

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working in a project where I derive some instances for a class. Since the class has only one method with will have the same definition save for a few specific cases, I tried defining an overlappable general instance and then defining the ones I need to be overlapping.

This doesn't work because I get an overlapping instances error. Doing some testing, we came accross this reduced example that's pretty much equivalent to my original problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Instance where

data Id a = Id a String

data C a = C a

class Bad a b where
  bad :: a -> String

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Bad a b where
  bad = \_ -> "Default case"

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Bad (Id a) (C a) where
  bad = \_ -> "Id"

class Good a b where
  good :: a -> String

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Good a b where
  good = \_ -> "Default case"

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Good (Id a) b where
  good = \_ -> "Id"

test = let a = Id () "a"
       in putStrLn (good a) >> putStrLn (bad a)
```

(Note that this won't compile unless you comment the second Bad instance.)

Class Good works without any problem (test outputs "Id"). If I don't remove the second instance for Bad, I get:

```
Overlapping instances for Bad (Id ()) b0
    arising from a use of ‘bad’
  Matching instances:
    instance [overlappable] Bad a b -- Defined at Instance.hs:12:31
    instance [overlapping] Bad (Id a) (C a)
      -- Defined at Instance.hs:15:30
  (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘b0’
   To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
   when compiling the other instance declarations)
  In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘(bad a)’
  In the second argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘putStrLn (bad a)’
  In the expression: putStrLn (good a) >> putStrLn (bad a)
```

What I don't understand is why does this happen, when the only difference between them is an aditional restriction in the second class parameter.

Also, isn't the point of overlappable instances to avoid overlapping errors?

Regards

Comment: These classes won't really work - the functions in the class do not mention the variable `b` and there is no fundep or the like to determine `b` from `a`. `Good` only works because of remarkable coincidence - in both instance for `Good`, the second type is a completely unrestricted type variable. This is essentially the same as if you didn't have the type variable in the class at all. `bad` does not work because `b` is a completely free type variable which may be instantiated to `C a` at some later time, which would change which instance is selected ("The choice depends on the instantiation").

Comment: I think your pragmas should have `AllowAmbiguousTypes` instead of `UndecidableInstances`, else you get a different error pertaining to `b` being ambiguous in the function signature `bad :: Bad a b => a -> String`...

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, I can see that, although the error is still there if you add b to the functions. Testing some more, I saw that you basically have to use the function while explicitely saying what is your b, that way ghc knows which instance to use. I could get this little example to work, but I don't think this is doable in the bigger project. Thanks!

Comment: If you read `Bad (Id a)` aloud, it sounds a lot like "bad idea". Overlapping instances are usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment above, I think your pragmas should have `AllowAmbiguousTypes` instead of `UndecidableInstances`,
else you get a different error (at least I do on GHC 8.0.1) pertaining to `b` being ambiguous in the function signature
`bad :: Bad a b => a -> String`.

`AmbiguousTypes` allows you to write signatures for functions that will be ambiguous when they are used.
Instead, the ambiguity check is moved to the call-site. This works really well with something like `TypeApplications`
to specify those ambiguous variables. In this case, `bad` is always ambiguous, so we need this pragma to move to the
error message at the call-site. Now, I have the same message as you.

---

The reason that even with `OVERLAPPABLE` and `OVERLAPPING`  Haskell complains is that depending on how `b` is instantiated (which hasn't been 
specified), it will choose one of the two instances of `Bad`. In other words, you *could* want `b` to unify with `C a`,
just as well as you could not, so Haskell throws up its hands and says "you haven't told me enough about `b` for me to be
able to pick a most specific instance of `Bad`".

On the other hand, even without knowing `b`, Haskell knows which of the instances `Good a b` and `Good (Id a) b` are more
specific - it is always the second one (even without knowing what `b` is that is the case).

I really recommend you read the documentation about [overlapping instances](http://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=incoherentinstances#overlapping-instances)
as it explains the whole algorithm.

---

You can usually get around these problems using things like `TypeApplications` (to specify `b`), or translating your type class to a type family.